# How can I "refresh" org-cite's bibliography?

Tags: org-mode

> Note: I'm using org-cite, not org-ref.

As I'm writing, I sometimes add a new citation to my references.bib file. But org-mode can't always find it.
Instead, org highlights the new citation as an error, and if I click on it says "Cannot find citation key".

However if I restart Emacs, it can find it.

Is there a function I can call to rebuild or refresh org-mode's understanding of the .bib file without having to restart Emacs?

Comment: Try `M-: (org-cite-basic--all-keys)`, There may be other, better supported ways, but this *should* parse the bibliography file again and remake the hash table. No guarantees though: my understanding of how citation works in Org mode is *extremely* rudimentary.

Comment: That function isn't defined in my version of emacs (28.1) and/or org (9.6). Maybe I need to upgrade...

Comment: It is in 9.6: maybe `oc-basic` is not loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I learned from [this post](https://kristofferbalintona.me/posts/202206141852/) about the variable `org-cite-global-bibliography`.

Setting this to point at my bibliography file AND removing the `#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: path/to/my.bib` from the org-mode buffer seems to fix my issue.

My suspicious is that the keyword-based bibliography information is cached but the `org-cite-global-bibliography` variable is not, which allows changes to either the .bib or .org file to be updated in the .org document with a call to `revert-buffer`.

In summary, my old method included this line inside each org-mode file:

```
#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: path/to/my.bib
```

My new method adds the following to my .emacs config file:

```
(setq org-cite-global-bibliography path/to/my.bib)
```

And omits the `#+BIBLIOGRAPHY:` line from the .org files.